# SQL and Case Insensitive Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, pdo

I have noticed in MySQL a where clause like `WHERE x = 'Test'` will match regardless of case ('TEST', 'test', etc.)

When using PDO, is it fair to assume that this is the case with most database servers? For example, If I were to use MSSQL or Oracle, would this be the same case?

Comment: @rabudde I thought that was the case, but I can assure you that the query is matching insensitively.

Comment: Case sensitivity depends on column's collation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the server that it depends on, but the collation. Most databases will default to a case insensitive collation, so you can assume that, but if you ever run into one that is case sensitive it is easy to change.

Comment: is it possible to have sensitive/non-sensitive collations on individual field basis? or is it across the board?

Comment: You can specify a collation not only for a particular column, but also for a particular comparison by specifying `COLLATE collation_name` where necessary.

Comment: You can specify a separate collation for each column that is a TEXT type (including VARCHAR and CHAR)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is case sensitive with data by default
e.g.

```
select * from 'test';
```

does not equal

```
select * from 'TEST';
```

Been a while since I last used them but I seem to recall Informix beiung case sensitive and Sybase I think is dependant on the collation.

As noted by other respondandt SQL Server is dependant on the collation.

So I think the only real answer is it depends on the RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is case insensitive by default. In SQL Server you can use Collation to use case sensitive comparisons, see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177439.aspx).

Oracle is case sensitive by default. You can use the 'UPPER' statement to perform case insensitive searches, see [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1558081�).

Comment: do you know if `UPPER` is standard to all SQL? Is there a list of standard functions / etc that I could use for reference? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, sql in general is case insensitive for string matching and that goes for almost all servers.

Here's an article showing how to do a case sensivive match in different ways though if you need it!

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm